# Selenium Tests not working on Jenkins with Chromedriver, Chromium and xvfb

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

im trying to get a bunch of selenium tests to work on my Jenkins. Its an Ubuntu machine and i installed Chromedriver Chromium and xvfb.

After some problems it seems like its finding my chromedriver and the xfvb now but i still cant get any tests to run. They work fine local but now on Jenkins it says :

```
Fehlermeldung

Timed out after 5 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id='loginForm-loginUsernameInput']
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-39-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Stacktrace

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 5 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id='loginForm-loginUsernameInput']
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-39-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:255)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:270)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:222)
```

Im wondering why it doesnt show the chromedriver Version? Like version unknown? Im running the xvfb and the chromedriver in the background and im not using Jenkins to start it. I tried it with letting Jenkins start chromedriver and set the path -Dwebdriver.chrome.path=
but that results in the same error. Does anyone have a idea about this? I tried quite a few things but im still wondering if its the chromedriver that is not working or whats the Problem? Im using ChromeDriver v2.9.248304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very outdated version of Selenium.  Typically, the newer Chrome versions might not work with older version of Selenium.

Try updating to Selenium version `2.44.0`

I'm willing to bet this will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks that actually helped. Althoug im getting a ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer. But i feel like im one step ahead.